# CSS Change color of ":after" element on hover

Tags: html, css

Lets say i have a list of elements :

```
<ol>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

When i hover a list item , i need to be able to get more info about each subject. I did this with CSS `:after` pseudo-element .

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
}

li:hover:after {
    content: " + More info";
}
```

[Here is a jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79Lvn/)

Now when i hover on the `More info` text , i want to change it's color . I don't really get it how to acheive this effect . 
i have tried the following css rules , but it does not work as expected .

```
li:after:hover {
    color: red;
}

li:hover:after:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Is it possible to do in CSS ?

If yes , another question is interesting , can i attach an `onclick` event to the `:after` element ?

Comment: You cannot achieve this using CSS and the :after psuedo tag, nor does it support the 'onclick' event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per ExtPro's comment, you can't

But you can do like...

**HTML :**

```
<ol>
    <li>First<span> + More info</span></li>
    <li>Second<span> + More info</span></li>
    <li>Third<span> + More info</span></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS :**

```
li > span {
    display:none;
}

li:hover > span {
    display:inline;
}

li > span:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

Use :active as onClick ?

```
li > span:active {
    color:blue;
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/79Lvn/2/

---

**or JS/jQuery way** ? just...

```
$('ol > li').append('<span> + More info</span>');
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/79Lvn/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i understand i can do it like that , but i was just curious if i could do it in pure CSS way .

Answer (score 48):

this works perfectly

```
.topButton:hover:after{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly !! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Best solution!!

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK, Hm... Why is this better? This answer has not solved the question. OW needs to style :after when :after is hovering

Comment: This will style the pseudo element when any part of .topButton is hovered, so it is not perfect nor an acceptable answer.

Comment: This will not set color as requested, only bgColor.

Answer (score -4):

Her you go mate, did a bit of "fiddling" and got it working with CSS using

```
.third:hover .sub{
      display:inline;   
}
```

:

http://jsfiddle.net/79Lvn/3/

Comment: i'm sorry I don't know what you mean? harsh down vote as I spent time figuring this code out