# Change color of :after on hover

Tags: css

I have a link which has a small drop down arrow after it, added using `:after`.

What I want to do is change the color of the arrow when I hover over the link, is this possible?

This is what I'm trying but doesn't work:

```
.detail__changer {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 33px;
}
.detail__changer:after {
    color: #333;
    content: ' ▾';
}
~ .detail__changer:hover:after {
    color: red !important;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sn0y1Lua/)

Also, [I have seen this question, my question is not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952986/css-change-color-of-after-element-on-hover)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me if I remove `~`, is that the problem?

Comment: Do you need something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/sn0y1Lua/2) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the tilde

```css
.detail__changer {
 color: #333;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 33px;
}
.detail__changer:after {
 color: #333;
 content: ' ▾';
}
.detail__changer:hover:after {
 color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail__changer">Hover over me</div>
```

Comment: I would take out the     !important for in order to make easy future modifications

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres It was there in anger - gone now, not needed

Comment: @DarrenSweeney `~` in css generally means proceeded by or a general sibling of. Similar to `+` but less specific in that it selects all siblings.