# Catch :hover event on :after selector

Tags: html, css

### Goal:

Create a simple text-box element with remove icon with `css3` only.
The icon should change his color to `blue` on `hover`.

### Progress:

It's pretty easy to achieve my wish with a little html and css code.

```css
.ui-textbox {  
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;             
    position: relative;
}
.ui-textbox span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.ui-textbox:hover:after {
    content:"x";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
    font-size: 16px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label class="ui-textbox">
    <span>Some label</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

### My Problem:

Can't find out how to catch the hover event on the after element so I could change his color.

Something like:

```
.ui-textbox:hover:after:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233991/combine-after-with-hover) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not "catch" :hover on `::after` pseudo-elements. I suggest the following using an extra element(like `span`):

```css
.ui-textbox {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.ui-textbox span {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.ui-textbox:hover span.cross {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  right: 20px;
  visibility: visible;
}
.ui-textbox span.cross {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.ui-textbox:hover span.cross:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="ui-textbox">
  <span>Some label</span>
  <input type="text" />
  <span class="cross">x</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I guess he wants to change color only while hovering over that icon.

Comment: @ManojKumar thanks for feedback. Check update answer :)

Comment: Thanks alex. I know I can do it in this way. I looked for more elegant way, so I won't need to add the `<span class'cross'>` everytime.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ui-textbox {  
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;             
    position: relative;
}
.ui-textbox span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.ui-textbox:hover:after {
    content:"x";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
    font-size: 16px;
    right: 20px;
}
.ui-textbox:hover:after {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="ui-textbox">
    <span>Some label</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/konsoetw/

Comment: Nope, he wants to change the color only while hovering over the icon :) Check Alex's answer

Comment: I agree that Alex's answer is ok.

Comment: It is possible with jQuery and You find here more answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952986/css-change-color-of-after-element-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is closer to what you want (just css):
http://jsfiddle.net/konsoetw/3/

```
    .ui-textbox {  
        padding: 0 10px 0 0;             
        position: relative;
    }
    .ui-textbox span {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    .ui-textbox:after {
        content:"x";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;    
        font-size: 16px;
        right: 20px;
        color:blue;
    }
    .ui-textbox:hover:before {
        color: red;
        content:"x";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;    
        font-size: 16px;
        right: 20px;
        z-index:10;
    }

 <label class="ui-textbox">
        <span>Some label</span>
        <input type="text" />
 </label>
```

Comment: The starting point should be with the icon hidden, But nice try.